# Discord.js and sql

Tags: javascript

```
    .setDescription(
${[result[1].name_hebrow]}
${[result[2].name_hebrow]}
)
```

How can I view the list without adding one at a time?
As if every attempt I made with this thing failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
.setDescription(`${result.map(e => {
    return e.name_hebrow
}).join(" ")}`)
```